# Saving an interface instance into a Bundle

Tags: android, interface, scene, game-state

All

I've have an interface that allows me to switch between different scenes in my Android game. When the home key is pressed, I am saving all of my states (score, sprite positions etc) into a Bundle.  When re-launching, I am restoring all my states and all is OK - however, I can't figure out how to save my 'Scene', thus when I return, it always starts at the default screen which is the 'Main Menu'.

How would I go about saving my 'Scene' (into a Bundle)?

**Code**

```
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public interface Scene{

void render();
void updateLogic();
boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event);

}
```

I assume the interface is the relevant piece of code which is why I've posted that snippet.

I set my scene like so: ('options' is an object of my Options class which extends MainMenu (Another custom class) which, in turn implements the interface 'Scene')

```
 SceneManager.getInstance().setCurrentScene(options);  //Current scene is optionscreen
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a piece of data to denote your scenes.  A simple enumeration is the easy way; even a string works just fine in a pinch.

Your interface should be extended to have something like

```
ESceneType getSceneType();
```

which returns the type of that scene (e.g. `ESceneType.MainMenu` or `ESceneType.Pause` or whatever).

You then create a factory object which, using either a data set or a hard-coded switch statement or the like, instantiates scene objects based on id.  The low-tech hard-coded version is something like

```
Scene createScene(ESceneType type) {
  switch (type) {
    case ESceneType.MainMenu: return new SceneMainMenu();
    case ESceneType.Pause: return new ScenePause();
    case ESceneType.Play: return new ScenePlay();
    default: throw error;
  }
}
```

Now you can save this scene type value easily, query it from the active `Screne` instance, and recreate a scene from it.

Comment: Hi @SeanMiddleditch - thanks for this, I don't quite understand how this works, what exacly is ESceneType?  I can currently get my scene type by doing the following: SceneManager.getInstance().getCurrentScene(); I'm don't quite understand how this can be used to save / recall the Scene - could you elaborate please?  Thanks!

Comment: "a simple enumeration" - just make an easy to serialize piece of data to identify your scenes and then reconstruct them when loading.  I'm assuming your `getCurrentScene` return an instance of a `Scene` derived type, not an identifier for the scene.  You have to make your own enumeration or string types here, or utilize Java's introspection APIs.  If you need any extra per-scene data you'll need to serialize that yourself, too.  How to do that is more of a basic programming/Java query not specific to game development.

Comment: I actually went for a similar but simpler form of this in the end, I held an simple int value and changed it when I changed the scene, then just saved that to / restored from the Bundle and switched it to set the current scene - simple :-)